# YouTube embeds without advertising not working anymore with adblocker

Tags: video, iframe, youtube, embed, ads

I don't know since how long it's going on, but today I noticed Chrome wasn't playing youtube embeds anymore. It used to work just fine. You get an "error occurred - please try again later". I re-installed Chrome but it didn't help.

I tried to debug further and when I switched off my adblocker the videos were playable again. Note, I play embeds that don't have any advertising enabled on the videos.

Do other people experience the same issue? Has adblocker changed how it handles embeds? Or is there still something wrong on my end?

Comment: And I heard users from my site confirm it. This seems to be an issue with AdBlocker (or a software update).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, seems to be a bug they are working on. I got this reply from twitter.

[image]